# Consulta de Sql para mostrarla en un DropDownList

Tags: sql, vb

**Quiero realizar una lista de selección por medio de un DropDownList pero no me genera nada, no se si tenga algún error**

```
    Protected Sub DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList4.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim conexion As New Conexion
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = conexion.conectar()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT (tipo_doc) FROM TipoDocumento", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    DropDownList4.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    DropDownList4.DataTextField = "tipo_doc"
    DropDownList4.DataBind()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Te sugiero mostrar la estructura de tu base de datos, así como los registros que en ella se encuentran para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Campos (IDTdocumento, tipo_doc) valores (1,2,3)(C.C, T.I, C.E)

Comment: Me parece que el problema es que le falta asignar el DropDownList4.DataValueField.  ¿Podrás probarlo?

Comment: Si no me equivoco ese código debería estar generando un bucle infinito. La carga de los datos lo debes hacer en una método y luego llamarlo en el load o donde corresponda. No en el indexChange!

Answer (score 0):

Si estas seguro que tu tabla tiene registros...

```
Private Sub CargarDropDownList4()
Try
    Dim connString As String = "Server=Myserver;Database=MiDb;Trusted_Connection=True"
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Conn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT tipo_doc FROM TipoDocumento", Conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    'Sirve para recuperar la selccion: DropDownList4.SelectedValue
    DropDownList4.ValueMember = "tipo_doc"
    'Sirve para que el usuario pueda ver las opcciones disponibles
    DropDownList4.DisplayMember = "tipo_doc"
    DropDownList4.DataSource = dt

    Conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Problemas:" & ex.Message)
End Try
```

End Sub

Estas cargando tu información en el evento **DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged** osea que cada ves que cambias la selección, vuelves a cargar la información (no se en que entorno estas trabajando, si es windows Form o web). Debes cargar la información una vez. por ejemplo:

```
Private Sub MiFormulario_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   CargarDropDownList4()
End Sub
```

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas Gracias :)